# Delphi 7 Sum of two numbers with decimals

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Beginner here :)

I am trying to make a Delphi application that requires user input and then adds and subtracts those variables.

I succeeded in creating the application and everything works fine except:

Cannot find the proper way to deal with numbers with decimals.

Example:

A,B,C,D,E,F: string;
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1: integer:

I use InputBox to get the user inputs.
I store the inputs in string variables.
I convert the string variable to integer with A1 := strToint(A);
At the end, I want to: A1+B1-C1-D1-E1-F1
End everything works if the input is integer.
The problem arises if the user enter a number with decimals.

I have searched all over the place but could not find an answer to my problem.(Or I did not understood)

Anyone can please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Try StrToFloat instead of StrToInt when the input string contains a decimal separator, and you'll need a variable of the correct type - Extended rather than Integer

Comment: The word you are searching for is "float" or "floating point number".

Comment: Also consider using meaningful variable names. If you will ever write somewhat more complicated code, meaningless variable names will drive you crazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to convert a string to a floating point value.

First of all you need to change your `Integer` variables to be of type `Double`. This will allow you to store values that are not integers.

Secondly you need a different function to perform the conversion. You should use `TryStrToFloat`. This attempts to convert from string to floating point. If the conversion succeeds the function returns `True`, otherwise it returns `False`. For example:

```
var
  str: string;
  value: Double;
....
if not TryStrToFloat(str, value) then
begin
  // handle error in some appropriate way
end;
// do something with value
```

Comment: +1, this is first thing everyone should learn, when converting strings to floating point values.

Answer (score 4):

As the name suggests, `StrToInt` converts a numeric string into its integer equivalent. There is also the analagous `StrToFloat` function for handling floating point numbers.

Your variables are currently defined as integers. If you want to use real/decimal numbers you will need to use the `Double` type.

I recommend you consult the Delphi documentation for more information on this.

Comment: Be careful when you talk about decimal numbers here. That term is usually used to mean a decimal base rather than binary. For instance in Delphi the decimal number type is `Currency`. Very different from binary floating point.

Comment: Or, if precision is important, use my Decimal type: http://rvelthuis.de/programs/decimals.html. That has 28 significant digits (or, to be more precise, a 96 bit mantissa/significand).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Pretty much off topic here. I hope the asker doesn't think that your Decimal type is the way to go here. ;-)

Comment: Not sure if it is off-topic. With floating point, you may get questions like "why isn't `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 = 0.3`?". Can't happen with my Decimal type. ;-)

Comment: @Rudy So what? You might also get a question like, *Why can't I perform trig with decimal types?*

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, it is better to teach how to compare floating point values. `Math.SameValue(Math.Sum([0.1,0.1,0.1]),0.3)` evaluates to true.

Comment: Oh, sure, it is better to teach people to use floats. I was not entirely serious, although decimals are much better in some areas. <g>